# php - webscraping - clicking an ajax call then scraping page (can do it in python)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, ajax

I have some code in python that scrapes a page and finds all elements with the class name 'group-head' and clicks them to generate a page with all ajax calls performed. This works in python but I wanted to know if it can be done on curl/php coding?

```
 # Get scraping...
tree = parseLxml(driver=driver, url=url) # Go to URL and parse
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('group-head') # Use ChromeDriver to find element to get to the Ajax call
for x in range(0,len(elem)): # Loop through all such elements
    try:  
        time.sleep(0.5)
        elem[x].click() # Click the element
        time.sleep(1.5) # Too fast and errors can occur, so wait...
    except:
        pass
newpage = driver.page_source # Need to get page source again now all visible
newtree = html.fromstring(newpage)
match = newtree.xpath('//td[contains(@class,"score-time")]/a/@href') # Scrape match link
base = 'http://uk.soccerway.com'
for m in match:
    mURL = base+str(m)
    print ('Match URL:',mURL)
```

Comment: I've done a fair amount of it from the back end scraping with PHP. I recommend [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Scrape it, find the elements, then "click" them by doing a file_get_contents or using curl to open the new page. Be careful though, headers/cookies and javascript loaded content can really through you off.

Comment: how do i open the page with the elements themself??

Comment: Any of the standard ways that you open a file in PHP - file_get_contents or CURL (I prefer the first in 90% of cases).

Comment: I have tried the above and it does not seem to fire the ajax as needed... would you be able to provide some sample code?

Comment: By `clicking an ajax call`, you mean to say evaluating `javascript` code dynamically at runtime, then it isn't that straight-forward even in `python`. In `python`, there are xml dom parsing libraries like `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup`, but to click an ajax button through code, you need a proper scraping framework like `mechanize`. I'm not aware of any such framework in `php`. What you can do is either use `mechanize` or `phantomjs` if you can use the `node.js` JavaScript platform.

Comment: The code above does that though... gets the links i need and everything i just cant run the script on my server

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the ChromeDriver so you should look for a PHP binding.

Have a look at https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver, you should be able to use it the same way.
Code not tested but should look like:

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // Selenium Host
$driver = ChromeDriver::create($host);
$driver->get($url); // Got to Url and Load Page
$elements = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::className('group-head'));
....
```

Comment: so does this mean running the phthon script through the php script?

Comment: no, with the php-webdriver for Selenium you can call the same ChromeDriver like you do in Python in PHP

Answer (score -2):

Yes thats possible with PHP :)

But you have to follow these steps..

1) Download the Dom Parser from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP

2) while clicking on the link in a page you can call using ajax which get the content of the file `(file_get_html)`.

3) And finally get the required data using its id, element, classname.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: you are just getting the source here, javascript will not be executed and you are not able to click on links to initiate ajax calls.

Comment: I hope the question is not getting done with ajax calls and js in the page. But to get some info in the page

Comment: That's exactly the question: How to trigger ajax calls dynamically and get the updated source of the page.